# why doesn't Jquery work, when js does?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am learning Jquery and i can't figure out why none of the JQuery lines execute, while javascript lines do.
When I open it whith browser, the console shows"hello world" and "undefined". If i put these lines in the console, they are executed as expected.
here is my code :`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> cim </title>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"> $('div:nth(0)').attr("class","marked") </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(funk())
        function funk() {
        $("div").css("border", "3px solid red");
            console.log("hello world");
            $("div:nth(0)").attr("class","marked");
            console.log($("div:nth(0)").attr("oo"));
            $("div").append("LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL");
        }
    </script>


</head>
<body>
<div oo="ooo">
<p> blah </p>
<p> blah <br></p>
<p>blah</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p> asd</p>
    <p> asd</p>
    <p > asd</p>
</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>enter code here`
```

Comment: Why are you including 2 different versions of jQuery in your page?

Comment: Also: `$(document).ready(funk);` not `funk()` - you're *calling* the function when you include `()`.

Comment: I see `</head>` but no `<head>`

Comment: Also, don't put any code in the `></script>` tags for the call to jQuery. Move `$('div:nth(0)').attr("class","marked")` to the script where the rest of your code is, within the `ready` function,

Comment: i deleted "()", works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A few of issues

1. You are including two versions of jQuery (*no need for that*)
2. You cannot run code and link to an external file in one `script` element. So the code inside the first one will be ignored
3. you immediately execute the `func` method and the DOM is not ready so all the elements are not found
4. there is not `:nth` selector. Either `:nth-child` or `:eq`

What you need is

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(funk);
    function funk() {
        $("div").css("border", "3px solid red");
        console.log("hello world");
        $("div:nth(0)").attr("class","marked");
        console.log($("div:eq(0)").attr("oo"));
        $("div").append("LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

change `$(document).ready(funk())` to this `$(document).ready(function () {funk();});`

Comment: Or just `$(document).ready(funk)`. There’s no point in over-complicating it.